# Cast date to varchar2 lost time part

Tags: oracle, casting

Any idea why the timestamp is lost after casting a date into a varchar (FYI : datatype is datetime in the rpd)
if I have a date like ;

date = 5/2/2011 9:18:26 AM
CAST (date as varcchar(100)) gives 5-2-2011, the time part is lost.

Don't know the reason of this, can anybody give me some explainin

According to the CAST instruction from Oracle official docs, it should be allowed to such cast.
[image]

Comment: Use `to_char()` you have much better control of the output format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17615/refrn10119.htm#REFRN10119):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'fmdd-mm-yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select cast(sysdate as varchar2(100)) from dual;

CAST(SYSDATEASVARCHAR2(100))
---------------------------------------------------------------------
14-1-2014

1 row selected.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'fmdd-mm-yyyy fmhh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select cast(sysdate as varchar2(100)) from dual;

CAST(SYSDATEASVARCHAR2(100))
---------------------------------------------------------------------
14-1-2014 14:17:43

1 row selected.
```

It's better to use TO_CHAR, as a_horse_with_no_name already suggested.

Answer (score 3):

`cast (date as varchar2)` will use the currently active nls_date_format, which, by default, does not include time.

To get the time included, you'd need to set the nls_date_format:

`alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';`

Or, without altering the session:

`to_char(date,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')`